# Adding views programatically to a relative layout within a scrollview

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

Please bear with me as I am new to the use of Views and Layouts.

I am trying to create an application in which the user can enter a text field, press a button and have a new text field appear and they can continue adding text fields in this way.

My solution was to have the top level be a scrollview and then have a relative view as a child within that(this way I can then programatically insert more editviews in my code with the OnClick() listener.

I have seen and read a couple of other posts pertaining to relative views but it seems there is still something that I am missing. I have tried

Here is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_create_accounts"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.nic.mybudget.CreateAccountsActivity">


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_create_accounts_relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/activity_name"
        android:inputType="textAutoComplete"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/activity_createAccounts_relativeLayout_activityName"/>


    <Button
        android:text="+"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/activity_createAccounts_relativeLayout_activityName"
        android:id="@+id/activity_create_accounts_relativeLayout_activityName_addButton" />

    <Button
        android:text="Save"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/activity_create_accounts_relativeLayout_activityName_addButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/activity_create_accounts_relativeLayout_activityName_saveButton" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the Code where I try to add new editviews.

```
public class CreateAccountsActivity extends Activity {

static private final String TAG = "MAIN-Activity";
int numAccounts = 0;
int lastAccountID;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_accounts);

    final RelativeLayout Relative = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_create_accounts_relativeLayout);
    final TextView oldAccount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.activity_createAccounts_relativeLayout_activityName);
    final TextView newAccount = new TextView(this);

    final Button addNewAccountButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.activity_create_accounts_relativeLayout_activityName_addButton);
    addNewAccountButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i(TAG, "addNewAccountOnClick");
            numAccounts = numAccounts+1;
            int newAccountID = oldAccount.getId() + numAccounts;

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
            newAccount.setLayoutParams(rlp);
            newAccount.setHint("Hint" );
            newAccount.setId(newAccountID);
            Relative.addView(newAccount);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams blp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            blp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, newAccountID-1);
            addNewAccountButton.setLayoutParams(blp);
        }
    });
}

}
```

As you can see what I am trying (and failing) to do is add the new edit view at the top of the page and simply push everything else down the page. What am I getting wrong here with the relative layout?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can use listview instead of relative layout inside scollview and add elements in a list and made it notifyDataSetChanged().  OR Use LinearLayout instead of Relative Layout.

Answer (score 3):

First thing View with id `activity_createAccounts_relativeLayout_activityName` is `EditText` and you are casting it with `TextView` so that is wrong cast it to `EditText`.

And to your actual problem:
You are using same `EditText` instance with variable `newAccount` and adding it again in relative layout if you want to add one more EditText in relative layout you have to initialise EditText inside onclicklistener.
Just add one line `newAccount= new EditText(context)`in your onclicklistener code before line `numAccounts = numAccounts+1;`

Happy Coding !